# Multiple attachments per model with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to integrate paperclip into a simple comment thread so users can attach files to their comments.

I understand that following the instructions that come with paperclip will end up with me being able to attach one file to one comment.

I would like to be able to attach multiple files. Do I need to create a separate 'Attachments' model with a has_many relationship?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating a separate attachment model linked by a `has_many` relationship is the best way to go.